# Javascript is not producing result in input type

Tags: javascript, function, input, time, types

I made below html to display a time based on variable factors.
Without any choices the result should display as 1 hour 30 minutes.
With choices that time will be shorter.

Problem: I can not get the result time from the function to display in the input type box.

I am sorry for noob mistakes as this is my first script

```js
function Clear() {
        document.calculation.reset();
        document.calculation.buff[0].focus();
}
        
function Calculate() {
// First check if only 2 crafting products are selected
    if (document.calculation.buff[3].checked &&
        document.calculation.buff[4].checked) {
            alert('does not work');
            document.calculation.time0.value = '';
            document.calculation.time1.value = '';
            document.calculation.time2.value = '';
            document.calculation.time3.value = '';
            document.calculation.time4.value = '';
    }
        else {


        factor = 60000;
        if (document.calculation.buff[0].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.8; 
        }       
        if (document.calculation.buff[1].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.5;
        }       
        if (document.calculation.buff[2].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.9;  
        }       
        if (document.calculation.buff[3].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.95; 
        }       
        if (document.calculation.buff[4].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.95;  
        }   


        if (document.calculation.stable[0].checked) {
  time0 = msTime(90);
         document.calculation.time0.value = time0;
  document.calculation.time0.focus();
        }
        else {
            document.calculation.time0.value = '';
        }                
}}



// function milliseconds to time
function msTime(s) {
  var ms = (s * factor) % 1000;
  s = (s - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = s % 60;
  s = (s - secs) / 60;
  var mins = s % 60;
  var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;
  return hrs + 'h ' + mins + 'm ' + secs + 's' + ms;
}
```

```html
<form name="calculation" id="calculation" action="#">

<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="0"> 0
<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="1"> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="2"> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="3"> 3
<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="4"> 4

<input type="button" value="Reset" id="pop" onclick="Clear()"></span><input type="button" value="Calculate" id="top" onclick="Calculate()">

<input type="checkbox" name="stable" value="0" checked> Result</td>
<input type="text" size="20" name="time0">

</form>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to delete one /td

Comment: You may want to add `.elements` after each `document.calculation`. E.g. `document.calculation.elements.stable.checked`

Comment: You code errors with quite specific, and easily understandable, errors in the javascript console. Did you work through them?

Comment: .elements does not work though.

Comment: I see only one error in the Google Chrome console. I know I made some basic mistake somewhere :( sorry it is my first script. Well actually it is my second one but based on the first. And the first did work, but not accurate enough.
Do not know how to add that part, it does not fit in this text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a number of things wrong with your html & javascript, lets start from the top and work our way down

---

Do not rely on the browser creating a variable under `document` for your form. The best thing to do is use `getElementById` to get a reference to the form, and then use the `.elements` object to reference the elements within it by name. Instead of repeating the below

```
document.calculation
```

do this once

```
var frm = document.getElementById("calculation");
```

Thereafter, you can use the following to reference an element

```
frm.elements["time0"].value = ''; // or frm.elements.time0.value = '';
```

---

Your html does not have fields `time1` through `time4`, remove these lines, they are causing javascript errors.

---

You reference the following field

```
document.calculation.stable[0].checked
```

However the html only has one field with that name `stable`, so this causes another javascript error. Remove the `[0]` (and use the suggestion above)

---

You have a function `msTime` which is expecting a number of milliseconds, and converts to a string in the form `xxxh yyym zzzs ms`. You are passing a number of minutes, rather than a number of milliseconds to it (`90` in oppose to `5400000`)

---

Your requirement seems to indicate you wish to multiply by the value of `factor` which you are calculating based on which checkboxes are checked. You're never doing the multiplication.

---

reformatted, and working version:

```js
function Clear() {
    var frm = document.getElementById("calculation");
    frm.reset();
    frm.elements.buff[0].focus();
}
        
function Calculate() {
// First check if only 2 crafting products are selected
    var frm = document.getElementById("calculation");
 if (frm.elements.buff[3].checked &&
                frm.elements.buff[4].checked) {
        alert('does not work');
        frm.elements.time0.value = '';
    }
    else {

        factor = 1;
        if (frm.elements.buff[0].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.8; 
        }       
        if (frm.elements.buff[1].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.5;
        }       
        if (frm.elements.buff[2].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.9;  
        }       
        if (frm.elements.buff[3].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.95; 
        }       
        if (frm.elements.buff[4].checked) {
                factor = factor * 0.95;  
        }   


        if (frm.elements.stable.checked) {
           time0 = msTime(5400000 * factor);
           frm.elements.time0.value = time0;
           frm.elements.time0.focus();
        }
        else {
            frm.elements.time0.value = '';
        }                
    }
}



// function milliseconds to time
function msTime(s) {
  var ms = (s * factor) % 1000;
  s = (s - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = s % 60;
  s = (s - secs) / 60;
  var mins = s % 60;
  var hrs = (s - mins) / 60;
  return hrs + 'h ' + mins + 'm ' + secs + 's' + ms;
}
```

```html
<form name="calculation" id="calculation" action="#">

<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="0"> 0
<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="1"> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="2"> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="3"> 3
<input type="checkbox" name="buff" value="4"> 4

<input type="button" value="Reset" id="pop" onclick="Clear()"></span><input type="button" value="Calculate" id="top" onclick="Calculate()">

<input type="checkbox" name="stable" value="0" checked> Result</td>
<input type="text" size="20" name="time0">

</form>
```

Comment: WOW this is GREAT! Thanks a lot for your work, I am sooooo happy now! It does give a weird seconds display when choices are made, have to round those to whole seconds.
I also added more stable, and all timeing work :D Thank you

Sorry I was such a noob, but this will make many players happy :D

Comment: No problem, we were all newbies once ;) (And yes, I left the rounding issue on seconds for you to deal with)

Comment: Not a problem, that will work out ;)

Many players will be happy with it. Thank you from the community

Comment: Is this a good idea? It does work fine visually, and the results seem correct
Changed a few things in the code:

<code>        if (frm.elements.stable[0].checked) {
   time0 = msTime(90);     // changed it to (minutes) instead of (millisecond * factor)

// and

function msTime(s) {
  var s = (s * 60 * 1000 * factor)          // added
  var ms = s % 1000;             // changed from (s * factor) to s</code>

Comment: You've made `factor` a global variable, that's generally agreed to be bad practice. If you've changed the function to take seconds (in place of milliseconds) update the name of the function to reflect that.

Comment: Learned something again, I will leave it as it was, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple but difficult to find error, use

```
document.calculation.stable.checked
```

instead of

```
document.calculation.stable[0].checked
```